# How to read data efficiently from Firestore

Tags: database, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-maps

I have 20,000 objects on firestore, all within one collection and each object will be a separate document.

The Objects have a Co-ords value inside them with the latitude and longitude.

When a user opens the map I want a marker to render on the map for each object with Co-ords that are within the map viewed on the screenr. (not all the markers all over the globe).
I'm planning on using the onRegionChangeComplete functionality to trigger the rendering of the markers.

The first idea I had was:
-To download all the data upon render of the map, and then use ForEach on the array of objects in order to work out which objects have a lat and lng within the map that's showing on the screen.

The other idea is:
To pull just the Lats, Lngs and Keys from Firestore, and then forEach over that array to work out which markers to render on the screen, and for the ones that render (due to being in the mapView), I pull the rest of the data in that object from Firebase (for when they click on the marker and I need to display more info).

[image: There will be up to 20,000 docs like this]

I would like the data to be read fast enough that there is only a half second delay or so between the map loading and the spots loading up. But I don't want to pay through the nose for it. Do you have any suggestions?

A related question:
Would it be better to download the data once and store it on the phone, and then have a listener which uses a forEach to render the markers up, and set up a listener to update the data whenever there is a change detected?

Comment: Maps and document are quite different things in Firestore. Instead of (only) describing your data structure in words, can you add a screenshot of the relevant document(s) and collection(s) from the Firestore console. It would also be good to know what you mean by "efficiently", as there are multiple ways to define that (cost to you, cost to your users, read performance, write performance, code size, etc).

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  Thanks guys, Ive added a screenshot, and I would like the data to be read fast enough that there is only a half second delay or so between the map loading and the spots loading up. But i don't want to pay through the nose for it. Is this possible. Also, the spots wont be updated regularly, so I could store the data locally and then just have a listener to update the data on the phone whenever there is a change? Thanks again